# Unable to update field datatype

Tags: tfs

I had to create a work item template.In order to do it quickly.I created all the fields by opening the template in notepad and copy pasting them with differnent name but same  datatype.

Then I import the template. Now I am trying to change the datatype form Open Wit from Server option , it is throwing me errors that datatype do not match . So I deleted those fields and reimported the templated.It is still throwing me the same error. I notice when I open work item field explorer then I can see the fields there. Even I have deleted them form workitem template.

So my question how can I delete Fields and work items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For TFS 2008:
- To delete a work item type, use the "DestroyWITD" from the power tools

For TFS 2010:
Use WitAdmin DestroyWitd and WitAdmin DeleteField: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx

Comment: What if you have a huge wit's already created using that field? I have to increase the length of string from 255 to store more chars and unfortunately I cannot delete the workitems as the data is created for last 4 years. :(

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx